# How to restrict roles on class parameters

Tags: haskell, ghc

The following code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingStrategies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

class C (f :: Type -> Type) where
  g :: String -> f a

class D a where
  h :: C f => a -> f a

instance C Maybe where
  g _ = Nothing

instance C (Either String) where
  g = Left 

instance D Int where
  h = g . show

newtype NewInt = NewInt Int deriving newtype D
```

fails to compile with the following error:

```
  Couldn't match representation of type: f Int
                           with that of: f NewInt
    arising from the coercion of the method ‘h’
```

Which I guess makes sense, if `f` does some weird type family stuff. But my `f`s do not, there just `Maybe` and `Either`, so replacing `Int` with it's newtype `NewInt` should probably work I believe.

How can I convince GHC of this (assuming I'm not wrong). I presume it's some `RoleAnnotations` thing required but nothing I have tried has worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can not at the moment specify roles of quantified type variables, unfortunately. The closest I was able to conjure is the following, leveraging safe coercions.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingStrategies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuantifiedConstraints #-}

import Data.Kind
import Data.Coerce

class (forall a b . Coercible a b => Coercible (f a) (f b))
      => C (f :: Type -> Type) where
  g :: String -> f a
```

Note the superclass requirement, which more-or-less requires a representational role, or more precisely its analogous with coercions.

The rest is the same code as yours:

```
class D a where
  h :: C f => a -> f a

instance C Maybe where
  g _ = Nothing

instance C (Either String) where
  g = Left 

instance D Int where
  h = g . show
```

We do have to change the `newtype .. deriving` to a custom instance, but at least we can simply call `coerce` and let it do its magic.

```
newtype NewInt = NewInt Int
  -- No "deriving newtype D" here

-- explicit instance using "coerce"
instance D NewInt where 
  h :: forall f. C f => NewInt -> f NewInt
  h = coerce (h @Int @f)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do this in GHC today. You cannot give role annotations to parameters of type variables (like your `f`).

Note that this is not special to type classes, you get the same problem with data types:

```
data E (f :: Type -> Type) a = MkE (f a)

foo :: E Maybe Int
foo = MkE Nothing

bar :: E Maybe NewInt
bar = coerce foo -- <<< error
```